# Problem regarding error of Taylor numerical method for solving ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Using $Taylor$ $method$ $of$ $order$ $2$ with step $h=0.5$ to solve  the following 
Cauchy problem : $y'=3t^ 2y^2$ with $y(0)=-1$

The exact solution is given as $y(t)=\frac{\ -1}{t^3+1} \\\\$

We get an error for $t=3$ of order $3.8*10^-3$ .

The question is to give an estimation of the step $h$ to get an error of the order $1.54*10^-4$.

Please help me I'm stuck with this problem I don't even know how to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you need to reduce the error by a factor of about $20$ and the method is of order $2$, you will need to reduce the step size by the square root of the factor, or about by a factor of $5$. So try with $h=0.1$.